# Showcasing 2 error bars based on seperate functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

My goal is to showcase two error bars as point ranges for the first and second standard deviation of my data. I've created two functions, "data_summary", and "data_summary_2", which I input into 'stat_summary', but I only get the second one drawn on my ggplot. I've marked where I'm having issues within my code. [image]

How can I create a plot that will showcase both of these error bars? I tried to summarize the data prior and merge it with the original datafile, but the error bars turned out wonky.

```
    df <- read.csv("data.csv")

# load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(EnvStats)


#Creating an empty list to save plots crated. Lists in R are very versatile.
#They can pretty much store any type of data in them
quantile_plot = list()

#Creating an empty list to save plots crated. Lists in R are very versatile.
#They can pretty much store any type of data in them
quantile_final = list()

#getting all the congeners that will be looped over

congener_list = unique(df$Congener)

#order by ascending and descending order for graphic to match up
df$Congener = with(df, reorder(Congener, order_num))

#looping over unique congener names
for (i in congener_list) {

#Get mean & Standard Deviation by Group
  data_msd <- df %>%                           
    group_by(Ethnicity_category, Congener) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(y),
                 list(mean = mean,
                      sd = sd)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
  data_msd
  
#merge these stats to main data frame
  df_merge <- merge(df, data_msd, by = c("Ethnicity_category", "Congener"))
  
#Make stat function for 1STDEV
  data_summary <- function(x) {
    m <- mean(x)
    ymin <- m-sd(x)
    ymax <- m+sd(x)
    return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
  }
  
  #Make stat function for 2STDEV
  data_summary_2 <- function(x) {
    m <- mean(x)
    ymin <- m-2*sd(x)
    ymax <- m+2*sd(x)
    return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
  }
  
df_merge %>% filter(Congener == i) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Ethnicity_category, y = y, color = Ethnicity_category, group = Ethnicity_category)) +
            labs(title =paste0('2003-2004 NHANES Males 60+ ', i), x = 'Ethnicity', y = 'ng/g Lipid Weight') +
            scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10') +
            scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
            theme_light() +
            stat_summary(fun.data = data_summary, color = "blue") +
            stat_summary(fun.data = data_summary_2, color = "blue")   #where I have the issue
            stat_n_text() +
            geom_jitter(
                shape = 19, alpha = 0.5, size = 5) +
                theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
                      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
                      axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
                      plot.title = element_text(size = 17),
                      legend.text = element_text(size=15)) -> quantile_plot[[i]]

#save to plots to disk
  ggsave(quantile_plot[[i]], file=paste0('V3_log_2003_2004_trends_', i, '.png'),
         width = 44.45, height = 27.78, units = 'cm', dpi = 600)
}
```

Comment: Well, the most likely reason is that you plot the second point range on top of the first. If you want to see both then I would suggest to nudge one to the left, the other to the right using e.g. `position = position_nudge(...)`.